# Is there a way to add columns to programatically to multiple queries?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have 24 queries from a pdf documents with data I want to transform. I want to append all the queries into a single one with all the data, but I would like to keep record from which query each line comes from. My idea was to add a custom column with just a id number to each query before appending them, but I would like to know if there a way to do this programmatically in power query so I don't have to go table by table?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

#### Step 1

Create a `new -> blank query` and name it `AllQueries`

#### Step 2

In the `Advanced Editor`, paste this code

```
let
    Source = Record.RemoveFields(
        #sections[Section1],
        "AllQueries", MissingField.Error
    ),

    Summary = Record.ToTable( Source )
in
    Summary
```

#### Step 3

Now expand/append or merge as needed, your `[Name]` column will be associated with that specific data.

#### How to Auto-ignore non-table Queries

A slightly longer query can automatically filter non-tables out, and, give each query a unique integer ID.

```
let
    Source = Record.RemoveFields(
        #sections[Section1],
        "AllQueries", MissingField.Error
    ),
    Summary = Record.ToTable( Source ),
    OnlyTables = Table.SelectRows(
        Summary, each Value.Is( [Value], Table.Type )
    ),
    #"Add Query Id" = Table.AddIndexColumn(OnlyTables, "Query Id", 0, 1, Int64.Type)
in
    #"Add Query Id"
```